# Enable update function for CRUD operations in MVC application in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller

I am trying to update the price of a Product in my MVC application, which is connected to a MySql database. I am using a javascript function that should open a textfield that is where the price can be updated. I have used this tutorial to help me out https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Implement-CRUD-operations-without-using-Entity-Framework-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx

My ProductController is the following:

```
 public class ProductController : Controller
    {
        
        // GET: Product
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<Models.Product> products = new List<Models.Product>();
            string constr = "server=localhost;user id=root;password=;database=accounting;persistsecurityinfo=True";
            string query = "SELECT * FROM product";
            using (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr))
            {
                using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query))
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    using(MySqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (sdr.Read())
                        {
                            products.Add(new Models.Product
                            {
                                productId = Convert.ToInt32(sdr["idproduct"]),
                                name = Convert.ToString(sdr["name"]),
                                description = Convert.ToString(sdr["description"]),
                                cost = Convert.ToDouble(sdr["cost"]),
                                price = Convert.ToDouble(sdr["price"]),
                                stockid = Convert.ToInt32(sdr["stockid"]),
                                sku = Convert.ToString(sdr["sku"])
                            });

                        }
                    }
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
            if(products.Count == 0)
            {
                products.Add(new Models.Product());
            }
            return View(products);
        }

       
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UpdatePrice(Models.Product product)
        {

            // First thing to do is to check that the User that is updating the Product is a StoreManager

            // to be completed late


            string query = "UPDATE product SET price=@price WHERE productId=@idproduct";
            string constr = "server=localhost;user id=root;password=qn3gt6abc7;database=accounting;persistsecurityinfo=True";

            using(MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr))
            {
                using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idproduct", product.productId);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", product.price);
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
            return new EmptyResult();
        }
    }
```

The Model is:

```
public class Product
    {
       

        public int productId { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public double cost { get; set; }
        public double price { get; set; }
        public int stockid { get; set; }
        public string sku { get; set; }
    }
```

And the View is the following:

```
@model IEnumerable<DE_Store.Models.Product>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
</head>
<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table" id="tblProducts">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.description)
        </th>
       
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.price)
        </th>
       
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td class="Product Name">
                <span>@item.name</span>
                <input type="text" value="@item.name" style="display:none" />
            </td>
            <td class="Description">
                <span>@item.description</span>
                <input type="text" value="@item.description" style="display:none" />
            </td>
            <td class="Price">
                <span>@item.price</span>
                <input type="text" value="@item.price" style="display:none" />
            </td>

            <td>
                <a class="Edit" href="javascript:;">Edit</a>
                <a class="Update" href="javascript:;" style="display:none">Update</a>
                <a class="Cancel" href="javascript:;" style="display:none">Cancel</a>
                <a class="Delete" href="javascript:;">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>

    }
</table>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //Edit event handler.
        $("body").on("click", "#tblProducts .Edit", function () {
            var row = $(this).closest("tr");
            $("td", row).each(function () {
                if ($(this).find("input").length > 0) {
                    $(this).find("input").show();
                    $(this).find("span").hide();
                }
            });
            row.find(".Update").show();
            row.find(".Cancel").show();
            row.find(".Delete").hide();
            $(this).hide();
        });
        //Update event handler.
        $("body").on("click", "#tblProducts .Update", function () {
            var row = $(this).closest("tr");
            $("td", row).each(function () {
                if ($(this).find("input").length > 0) {
                    var span = $(this).find("span");
                    var input = $(this).find("input");
                    span.html(input.val());
                    span.show();
                    input.hide();
                }
            });
            row.find(".Edit").show();
            row.find(".Delete").show();
            row.find(".Cancel").hide();
            $(this).hide();

            var product = {};
            product.idproduct= row.find(".productId").find("span").html();
            product.name = row.find(".Product Name").find("span").html();
            product.price = row.find(".Price").find("span").html();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Product/Index",
                data: '{product:' + JSON.stringify(product) + '}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json"
            });
        });

        </script>
```

When I run it I encounter issues with the javascript part, when I click on the Edit button nothing happens, and by inspecting the page for errors I am getting are:
Mixed content: load all resources via HTTPS to improve the security of your site.
The resources files involved are
Name    Restriction Status
jquery.min.js   blocked
json2.js    blocked

Is there anything I can do to fix this? Any suggestion for the javascript code, or any alternative solution to update the price of the product?

Comment: use https for scripts you load, as suggest the error message? `src="https://ajax.` for both jquery and json2

Comment: That does the trick, thank you so much. I didn't even look at that...